# Как хранить критическую информацию (токены доступа к сервису) в Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу проект на PHP+Mysql, который будет получать информацию по API из другого сервиса.
Необходимо для этого хранить токены доступа к нему. Ясно, что плэйнтекстом совсем не вариант. Как безопасно их сохранить?

Comment: ну как сказать, да хоть зашифрованные храни, если кулхацкер имеет доступ к твоим скриптам, расшифровать их не проблема.

Comment: Ясно дело, что любая система может быть подвержена достаточно кул хацкеру. Вопрос в том, чтобы если человек получит доступ к БД - хотя бы не сразу получил доступы к токенам.

Comment: ну так зашифруй по своему алгоритму, какой ответ ты ожидаешь от нас?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете хранить эти токкены прямо на свое сервере. Главное потом не добавить их в репозиторий или публичный доступ.
Для линукса есть красивое решение, когда вы в настройках bash создаете переменную с токкеном вашего сервиса, а в самой программе обращаетесь к ней.
Посмотрите вот этот пример https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9MRCxq4DIc